# Why is __code__ for a function(Python) mutable

Tags: python, internals, python-internals

In a previous question yesterday, in comments, I came to know that in python `__code__` atrribute of a function is mutable. Hence I can write code as following

```
def foo():
    print "Hello"

def foo2():
    print "Hello 2"

foo()
foo.__code__ = foo2.__code__
foo()
```

Output

```
Hello
Hello 2
```

I tried googling, but either because there is no information(I highly doubt this), or the keyword (`__code__`) is not easily searchable, I couldn't find a use case for this.

It doesn't seem like "because most things in Python are mutable" is a reasonable answer either, because other attributes of functions — `__closure__` and `__globals__` — are explicitly read-only (from [Objects/funcobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c#L236)):

```
static PyMemberDef func_memberlist[] = {
    {"__closure__",   T_OBJECT,     OFF(func_closure),
     RESTRICTED|READONLY},
    {"__doc__",       T_OBJECT,     OFF(func_doc), PY_WRITE_RESTRICTED},
    {"__globals__",   T_OBJECT,     OFF(func_globals),
     RESTRICTED|READONLY},
    {"__module__",    T_OBJECT,     OFF(func_module), PY_WRITE_RESTRICTED},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

Why would `__code__` be writable while other attributes are read-only?

Comment: You can't prevent any sort of this 'nefariousness' in Python, `__code__` or not. Either trust the modules used, or don't use them.

Comment: Yes. I have found that to be usually the case. But still thought to ask.

Comment: Practice safe stacks instead of hooking into strange APIs.

Comment: It's a peculiar design choice I'll give you that. Everything on a function aside from `__globals__` and `__closure__` is writeable. Why only those two are read-only is anyone's guess.

Comment: @AkshatHarit Whoops, it looks like my answer ("most things in Python") is not helpful. I hope you'll forgive me for editing your question a bit to clarify why this is actually an interesting and not straight forward question.

Comment: Also, to your questions about security/privacy: Python was never designed to be "safe" from other developers in the way that languages like, ex, Java are "safe". There are a *myriad* of ways a nefarious developer could break an application (`sys.modules`, `__builtins__`, and changing globals in other modules, just to name a few), so (for better or worse) you've got to trust that developers aren't malicious.

Comment: @DavidWolever No problem in editing. Also to clarify, I am not that concerned about the security/privacy part. It was an easy example I could come up with in a pinch, so suggested that. It is good that you edited it out as the question was going more in the security stuff. I am more interested in design considerations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact is, most things in Python *are* mutable.  So the real question is, why are `__closure__` and `__globals__` *not*?

The answer initially appears simple.  Both of these things are containers for variables which the function might need.  The code object itself does not carry its closed-over and global variables around with it; it merely knows how to get them from the function.  It grabs the actual values out of these two attributes when the function is called.

But the scopes themselves are mutable, so this answer is unsatisfying.  We need to explain why modifying these things in particular would break stuff.

For `__closure__`, we can look to its structure.  It is not a mapping, but a tuple of cells.  It *doesn't know the names of the closed-over variables*.  When the code object looks up a closed-over variable, it needs to know its position in the tuple; they match up one-to-one with `co_freevars` which is also read-only.  And if the tuple is of the wrong size or not a tuple at all, this mechanism breaks down, probably violently (read: segfaults) if the underlying C code isn't expecting such a situation.  Forcing the C code to check the type and size of the tuple is needless busy-work which can be eliminated by making the attribute read-only.  If you try to replace `__code__` with something taking a different number of free variables, [you get an error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c#L269), so the size is always right.

For `__globals__`, the explanation is less immediately obvious, but I'll speculate.  The scope lookup mechanism expects to have access to the global namespace at all times.  Indeed, the bytecode may be [hard-coded](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL) to go straight to the global namespace, if the compiler can prove no other namespace will have a variable with a particular name.  If the global namespace was suddenly `None` or some other non-mapping object, the C code could, once again, violently misbehave.  Again, making the code perform needless type checks would be a waste of CPU cycles.

Another possibility is that (normally-declared) functions [borrow a reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#reference-count-details) to the module's global namespace, and making the attribute writable would cause the reference count to get messed up.  I could imagine this design, but I'm not really sure it's a great idea since functions can be constructed explicitly with objects whose lifetimes might be shorter than that of the owning module, and these would need to be special-cased.

Comment: I don't buy the `__closure__` explanation: adding a setter that does some type checking would be easy (see, ex, the setter for `__code__`, which does exactly that: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c#L254)

Comment: @DavidWolever: It's still one of the *least* user-friendly interfaces out there.  You have to get the variable order right, and it's not a tuple of normal objects but a tuple of "cells."  Perhaps the type checking code is simply more trouble than it's worth, in the minds of the core developers.

Comment: I definitely don't buy the `__globals__` argument, considering that `g = {k:v for k,v in func.__globals__.items() if k in allowed}; new_func = types.FunctionType(func.__code__, g, func.__name__, func.__defaults__, func.__closure__)` is valid python

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: Have you tried it with `None`?  I imagine that throws.

Comment: Yep, TypeError. It did let me make a function with an defaultdict for globals, though

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: I suppose it would be fairly easy to slap a `None` check onto the `__globals__` descriptor, so I came up with another possibility.  It's a bit of a stretch, though.  If anyone's willing to go source diving, the answer might be in the code.