# How to pass function reference without using mutable type like list or dict

Tags: python, function, pass-by-reference, immutability

**My goal**: pass a reference to a function, and be able to update the function later on.

In Python, I believe functions are passed by reference, but a function's reference is considered immutable.  Thus, the function can't be updated later on.

This question gets at the core problem: [Python functions call by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13299427/11163122)

The answers all point at the workaround: pass the function within a mutable type such as a `list` or a `dict`.

I am wondering: **is there a more direct way?**  Might there be some `functools` function, `types` utility, or external library that enables this behavior?

---

**Sample Code**

**Update**: I am not interested in making `foo._on_call` public.  I am trying to change `on_call` externally via a reference, not by actually operating directly on the `foo` object.

```py
from typing import Callable, List

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, on_call: Callable[[], int]):
        self._on_call = on_call

    def __call__(self) -> int:
        return self._on_call()

def do_something() -> int:
    return 0

def do_something_else() -> int:
    return 1

foo = Foo(do_something)

do_something = do_something_else  # Updating do_something
print(do_something())  # This prints 1 now
print(foo())  # This still prints 0, I want this to print 1 now too
```

Known (undesirable) workarounds:

- Pass `do_something` within a list
- Recreate the `foo` object
- Making `Foo`'s `_on_call` attribute public or using a `property` decorator

Python version: 3.8

Comment: more direct way: `foo._on_call = do_something_else`

Comment: Could you give some more context? This seems like it could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are actually mutable, via [`__code__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__code__#code-objects). [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31599376/4518341). However, don't know if this is a good idea.

```
do_something.__code__ = do_something_else.__code__
print(do_something())  # -> 1
print(foo())  # -> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning `do_something = do_something_else` outside of `Foo` does not change the function that was known as `do_something`, it just points the name `do_something` in the module scope to a different function. The name `_on_call` in the `Foo` instance's scope is not affected by that and still points to the original function.

The simplest and most idiomatic way to achieve what you want is to make `_on_call` a public attribute of a `Foo` instance, or add a method that updates it:

#### 1. attribute

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, on_call):
        self.on_call = on_call
    # ...

foo = Foo(do_something)
# ...
foo.on_call = do_something_else
```

(You do not have to rename the attribute to be able to do that, but it's good style to treat attributes beginning with an underscore like they are not supposed to be accessed from outside the class.)

#### 2. method

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, on_call):
        self._on_call = on_call
    def update(self, on_call):
        self._on_call = on_call
    # ...

foo = Foo(do_something)
# ...
foo.update(do_something_else)
```

Comment: FWIW, another option is making it a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) with a setter. This is just like an attribute but with more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you @mkrieger1 for proposing a workaround.  However, I am trying to figure out if I can pass a function by reference without using `list` or `dict`, not working around it by changing the exposed interface of `Foo`

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Well, you can sneakily assign `foo._on_call = do_something_else`, since `_on_call` is not considered part of the public interface, but that would be bad style.